# Instance vs Object. Instance of an abstract class principle?

Tags: c#, oop, object, instance, abstract-class

I have read in a book:

> At the top of the character stream hierarchy are the **abstract
>   classes** `TextReader` and `TextWriter`.

In the same book it says that:

> it is not possible to create an object of abstract class, we can use
>   it only through inherited class which overrides the abstract .

But `Console.In` is an **instance** of `TextReader`. How can the instance be created from the `abstract` class? can some one explain it. What is the difference between `instance` vs `object`.

Comment: `Console.In` is instance of some class derived from `TextReader`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I don't think `Console` class has any parent, other than `System.Object`. Can you explain? or I'm confused?

Comment: @Zeeshan I did not say anything about `Console` class parents.

Comment: @PetSerAl I was confused, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between instance and object ?

An instance is an object in memory. Basically you create object and instantiate them when you are using them.

> But Console.In is an instance of TextReader.

If you do

```
  Type res = Console.In.GetType();
```

and inspect it .then you get something like [image]

Note that base here is `SynctextReader`  which derives from `TextReader`.

The declaration in C# would look something like:

```
namespace System.IO
{
   public class TextReader
   {
      class SyncTextReader : TextReader
      {
      }
   }
}
```

So `Console.In` is not a instance of `textReader` instead it belongs to `SyncTextReader`

Answer (score 2):

Ok let's take `Console.In` - on my system (Mono 4 right now) at run time it's type is:

```
Console.In.GetType()
{System.IO.CStreamReader}
```

(this is right from the direct-window - I left the other stuff ;))

So even if the property `In` of the `static` `System.Console` class is of type `TextReader` the actual value of it can of course be any derived class of `TextReader` (so `CStreamReader` just have to be derived from `TextReader` somehow).

That's basically the *magic* behind inheritance - you can write code that works for **any** `TextReader` even if you cannot ever create one of those directly.

By the way you don't have to think of *abstract*  classes to realise this - just think of *interfaces* - those are in a sense the most abstract *things* of all (because in .NET they cannot contain only *abstract* members) - you cannot instanciate an interface directly - but you can of course give object whose classes implement it.

### demonstration

sadly you cannot *set*  the `Console.In` property as it's readonly (and I did not want to use some reflection magic) so I had to create my own `MyConsole`):

```
static class MyConsole 
{
    public static System.IO.TextReader In { get; set; }

    public static string ReadLine()
    {
        return In.ReadLine ();
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (line);
    }
}
```

but here you can see that you now can set the `.In` property and it will use the `StringReader` instance:

```
var reader = new System.IO.StringReader ("Hello you\nwhat's up");
MyConsole.In = reader;
var l1 = MyConsole.ReadLine ();
MyConsole.WriteLine (l1);
var l2 = MyConsole.ReadLine ();
MyConsole.WriteLine (l2);
```

try it - you will see it reads the `"Hello you"` and `"what's up"` lines and print them out.

Comment: *sadly you cannot set the `Console.In` property as it's readonly* Did not Mono have [`Console.SetIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.setin.aspx) method?

Comment: no ... that's why I used `MyConsole` (I showed all the code there)

Answer (score 0):

It is called [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).  The class name of the object you are seeing as "TextReader" is the Console.in, since Console.in inherits from TextReader

To answer your question of "What is the difference between instance vs object"
please [see this explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).  I know this link is Java related, but it should help you understand the concepts.